# Download all dependency java libs (recursively)

Tags: java, maven

How can I download all the dependencies of a given artifact recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific command for doing this:

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

It will cause all dependencies needed to build the current project to be downloaded to the local repository.

Subsequently, you can either implicitly operate offline without a connection, or force offline mode using `-o`:

```
mvn -o compile test
```